# How to automatically run a command when cursor is at bottom of visible frame?

Tags: frames

The recenter command in emacs is `recenter-top-bottom` which I can invoke using `Ctrl-l`. How can I call this command automatically every time the cursor is on the fifth-last line in the visible frame?

**[Context]**

I am manually editing one column in a large csv file with `4000` rows and I have turned on `overwrite mode` and I have remapped the `0` and `1` keys so that they automatically add a new line, like this:

```
(local-set-key (kbd "1") (lambda () (interactive)
 (self-insert-command 1) (next-line) (left-char)))
```

So I don't have to press any arrow keys. One last thing that I want to automate is the recentering.

Comment: Have a look at the variable `scroll-margin`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer :)